# Difference between 1 :: 2 :: Nil vs. (1 :: (2 :: Nil))?

Tags: scala

In the Scala tutorials I have been using, I have always seen lists constructed in this manner:

```
(1 :: (2 :: Nil))
```

Is there a difference between this and the non-parentheses version?

```
1 :: 2 :: Nil
```

Comment: What kind of difference could it possibly be? How could you test that?

Comment: Mostly just a question regarding optimization; like I was wondering if there is an actual difference in how the list is constructed with one being more efficient than the other.

Comment: It's for helping the reader understand the order of execution. Otherwise, they're identical.

Comment: Understood, many thanks.

Comment: That's just silly, it's not unreasonable to have my question when learning the language.

Comment: Why is it silly? If you believe, there might be a difference, you should seriously measure. Writing the code to produce such classes is a good lesson in computing anyway. Maybe there is a difference of only 10% or less? Or the difference is 40%, but in total it is so small, that you'll never experience a difference?  But 100.000 elements might be exaggerated. There are compiler limits for class files. Better start with 2000.

Comment: I had this question because the purpose of parentheses is to control order of operations; if they are used it leads to asking why they are needed.

As far as your suggestion, it really is silly because it is ultimately inconclusive. Even if a difference is found, you are still unable to identify the underlying reason why a difference exists. This is a conceptual question about the language, taking benchmarks does not answer that question.

Comment: So is your question about the efficiency of the generated byte code, or about the process of compilation? What else would uncover inefficient code, if not doing a comparing measuring? And you may measure both, the compiling process and the usage of each of the classes, generated that way. Since it is obvious to me, that both should compile to the same byte code, I might have premature assumed, you're talking about the compiler. Btw.: My compiler said bye, when confronted with a list of 1000 literal elements. I'll go now for 512. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are same when compiled by *Scala compiler*

```
(1 :: (2 :: Nil))
//res0: List[Int] = List(1, 2)
```

And

```
1 :: 2 :: Nil
//res1: List[Int] = List(1, 2)
```

The brackets used are just to show the grouping and order of prepending in a list as `Nil` being the last element.

Answer (score 6):

They are the same. The parentheses can be added to illustrate the order of operation but they don't change anything. In fact they're rather pointless because no other order of operation is possible. In both cases the infix (i.e. dot-less) notation is de-sugared to the following.

```
Nil.::(2).::(1)
```

"How's that," you say? Remember that method names ending with a colon, `:`, reverse the `class.method(argument)` order when using infix notation.